# Count blanks in multiple columns, grouped by another value

Tags: sql

Ok so this gets me the count of how many Records of type A are blank in column B

```
SELECT A, Count(B)

FROM `table1` 

where

B  = ""

group by A
```

it gives me a table

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| First | 564 |
| Second | 1985 |

And that is great. But I want this to summarize by counting blanks in multiple columns, not just blanks in column B, like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 564 | 9001 |
| Second | 1985 | 223 |

I have an intuition that this is done by creating another table first that would look like this

| A | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | "B" | B value |
| First | "C" | C value |
| Second | "B" | B value |
| Second | "C" | C value |

for every document, so you can count blanks, but I'm not sure how to get there. Is this the right approach? or is there a much simpler version using pivot tables or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a conditional sum,

```
select A,
    Sum(case when b='' then 1 end) B,
    Sum(case when c='' then 1 end) C
from t
group by A
```

Comment: thank you! that is so much cleaner than I was expecting!